# ARC: returning allocated object from a method called by performSelector, is it OK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, performselector

I'm not sure if i cause a leak here, is it ok to return allocated NSError back to
the calling method by perform selector?
Is it OK to create the NSMutableArray and store it in the same object i got for the callback? and later pass it to the delegate?
The code works fine, but because i'm new to arc i have the fear of doing something wrong.

(i'm using perform selector because my selector is dynamic. just for the example i wrote it statically).

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self.client HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        //-----------------Callback--------------------

        #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
        SEL callback = @selector(getOperationCallback:);
        NSError *error = [self performSelector:callback withObject:operation];

        //------------------Delegate Call---------------
        if(operation.delegate)
            [operation.delegate onFinish:operation.requestIdentifier error:error 
                                                    data:operation.parsedObject];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        //------------------Delegate Call---------------
        if(operation.delegate)
            [operation.delegate onFinish:operation.requestIdentifier error:error data:nil];

    }];

- (NSError *)getOperationCallback:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation{

    NSArray *rawJson = (NSArray *)operation.jsonObject;
    NSError *error;

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(id json in rawJson){
        MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] initWithJson:json];
        if(object){
            [array addObject:object];
        }else{
            error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"myErrors" code:1000 userInfo:nil];
            break;
        }
    }

    operation.parsedObject = array;

    return error;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it ok to return allocated NSError back to the calling method by perform selector?
>
> Is it OK to create the NSMutableArray and store it in the same object
>   i got for the callback?
>
> and later pass it to the delegate?

Answer to all questions are OK, nothing wrong with anything. All objects are created in autorelease way.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `performSelector:` in ARC could only cause a leak, if the selector you pass to it starts with `alloc`, `new`, `retain`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`.

Comment: Or `__attribute__((ns_returns_retained))` or `__attribute__((objc_method_family(<alloc,copy,mutableCopy,new>)))`

Answer (score 0):

As long as the return value of the method your are invoking via `performSelector:withObject:` is an object, it's perfectly ok to do that.

It won't leak since ARC will take care of releasing `array` and `error` is autoreleased.

Answer (score 0):

In general, steer clear of `performSelector:`. The reason being that ARC cannot help you. Even if you think your app works and you've tested that it does, it might break later down the line when you change something.

Sure, if the selector you're calling does not start with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`, etc then it won't be a problem. But there's cases, such as using `__attribute__((ns_returns_retained))` that make it non-obvious that a method might return something retained. In any case, having code that ARC cannot help you out with, is a bad thing.

There's always a way to make it such that you don't have to use `performSelector:`. Why not make use of a callback block for example?